# The correct design: Including module in ActiveRecord or helper method

Tags: ruby, activerecord, coding-style, module, sinatra

I have a Sinatra application using ActiveRecord and I wish to add a feature where I can generate a fingerprint (SHA1) for a set of records.

The way I've implemented this is by defining a module and including it within `ActiveRecord::Relation` as follows:

```
module Fingerprints
  def sha1
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest map{ |record| record.attributes.values.join }.join
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Relation.send :include, Fingerprints
```

I can now call 'sha1' on a `ActiveRecord::Relation` and get the value I need.

My question is whether this is the "preferred" way to be doing this (extending ActiveRecord with additional functionality)?

The final line that uses `send` feels unclean to me and the simple fact that I'm bolting features onto a class that isn't my own also feels like a hack. I know this is a standard pattern in Ruby but reaching into ActiveRecords guts and patching it in this way is unfamiliar to me.

The alternative is to create a Sinatra helper that takes a `ActiveRecord::Relation` and returns the fingerprint. While this feels cleaner, I can't help feeling that the `sha1` method should really belong to the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class to better describe it's intent.

This might be simply down to personal preference but I'd be interested how others do this and whether there is a feeling of the "right" way this is done.

Thanks

Comment: Why add it to ActiveRecord when you can add it to the individual model classes?

Comment: Because I want to be able to generate a fingerprint for a _set_ of records. When you execute `Model.scoped`, for example, an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` is returned containing model objects. It's the set I want to generate the fingerprint for, not the individual model (I've already added fingerprinting for individual models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all honesty I can't see any real problem with what you've done. *Perhaps* call the method `fingerprint_sha` to prevent clobbering, *maybe* add an custom exception so that if any problems occur you know that it started in your code and not AR's.

Personally, I'd probably have made this a helper and passed in the relation, it could well be more obvious where the method was defined for others if it's in the helpers, but like I say I don't see a problem with what you've done and think it's a good solution.

Maybe someone else will come along and say different and we'll both learn something here :)

Comment: That's the idea. I code most of my Ruby on personal projects in my own time so getting exposure from other developers on the "right" way of doing things is difficult to come by. I've the feeling that a helper would be clearer aswell, but it's still 50/50 in my mind

Comment: @philostler I can recommend Russ Olsen's "Eloquent Ruby" for an idiomatic approach to writing it. Aside from that, reading the source code of projects like Sinatra is really helpful, but a lot of the best known projects have the least comments… :/

Comment: I have his "Design Patterns in Ruby" which is a good read also. That also looks a worthwhile read. Thanks for the tip, very valueable